groupby and combine column with "\n"
I wish to combine column value with \n to the same cell if name is the same.
e.g.
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['A','x'],
    ['A','y'],
    ['A','z'],
    ['B','m'],
    ['B','n'],
    ['B','o'],
    ['B','p']
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name','value'])
print(df)
dfg = df.groupby('name')


Expected output:
  name value
0    A     x
           y
           z
1    B     m
           n
           o
           p



OK, what's the question? If you don't know how to aggregate a groupby, there's a section in the user guide: Aggregation, more specifically, Aggregation with User-Defined Functions. If you've read that and you're having difficulty, please [edit] and show what you've tried. For more tips, see [ask].

Sorry, maybe I should have started with: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, so posts should contain a question or at least make it clear what you need help with.

df.groupby('name', as_index=False).agg('\n'.join)?

For a nice display: print(tabulate(df.groupby('name', as_index=False).agg('\n'.join), tablefmt='plain', headers='keys', showindex=True))

You can simply do an apply after groupby to join the values. I'm not sure how "\n" will behave inside col but try it out. I have not run it but this is just to give you an idea on how to do it.
dfg = df.groupby(['name'])['value'].apply(",".join).reset_index()

